# How to implement something like "Fences"

Tags: c#, .net, windows-desktop-gadgets

I am fascinated by the program "Fences"

How can I implement something which resides on the desktop like it does?
you can move around the fences and they are persistent.

[image: image i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim//2009/10/05/Foreman_11108546_4825_fences_210x158.jpg]
<sub>(source: [com.com](http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim//2009/10/05/Foreman_11108546_4825_fences_210x158.jpg))</sub>

My guess is that it has been implemented using a dot net language. Can this be done in C# ?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that Fences is written in a .NET langage, but it's more likely to be written in C++. A program like this requires very tight integration with the Win32 API - which can be done from .NET, but is easier with C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Shell extensions required to be coded using a language tied to the Win32 API.

The 'appearance customization window' might be coded using .Net, but the core program is probably C++.

Comment: (answer to a deleted comment)Yeah, but it's a real PITA. And there is no point to do it in .Net IMHO.

Comment: There are libraries that reduce the pain, and the pain comes from the shell itself, not the use of C#. There is a point if you don't know C++ very well or want some other productivity gains granted by a managed language. I deleted the original comment because you amended your answer.

Comment: C++/CLI would probably give a good balance between Win32 interop and .NET productivity